# How to get value of variable from inside of class in Python?

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

So, im writing some simple code in *python pygame*, just to learn. I encountered problem, when i want to check **collisions** of ball whether it is the same as **y** possition of my pallete. The main problem is that the value of variable of my pallete is updating by the user, and it sits inside class pallete, in function **move**. How can i get it out and put it outside class, into function holding ball?

```
import pygame
from pygame.constants import DROPTEXT
pygame.init()
#window
w_width = 1000
w_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w_width, w_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
open = True
#player
x,y = 100,250
#define player action variables
speed = 5
speed_x,speed_y = 5,4
moving_down = False
moving_up = False
#define ball action variables
x_ball,y_ball = 500,250
radius = 30
class palette(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    global x,y

    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
        self.speed = speed
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.player_rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,30,100)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'White', self.player_rect)

    def move(self, moving_up, moving_down):
        #reset movement variables
        global dy
        dy = 0

        #assing movement variables if moving up or down
        if moving_up:
            dy = -self.speed
        if moving_down:
            dy = self.speed

        #update pallete possition
        self.player_rect.y += dy
        
def ball():
    global speed_x,speed_y,x_ball,y_ball
    #update pos of bal
    x_ball += speed_x
    y_ball += speed_y
    #basic colision with screen
    if x_ball>=w_width-(0.5*radius) or x_ball <=0+(0.5*radius):
        speed_x*=-1
    if y_ball>=w_height-(0.5*radius) or y_ball <=0+(0.5*radius):
        speed_y*=-1
    #collision with pallettes

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,255), (x_ball,y_ball), radius, 5)

#build players and enemies
player = palette(x,y, speed)
enemy = palette(x*9,y, speed)
#game
while open:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #quit game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            open = False
        #keyboard presses
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                moving_up = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                moving_down = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                open = False
        #keyboard button released
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                moving_up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                moving_down = False
    
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip


    #keys


    #init players
    player.draw()
    enemy.draw()
    enemy.move(moving_up, moving_down)
    player.move(moving_up, moving_down)
    ball()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects). The "variables" in a class are called "attributes". You can access the instance attributes through the instance object. In your case `player` and `enemy` are instances of the class `palette`.  The `palette` class has a `player_rect` attribute which is a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. Therefore:

```py
y = player.pylyer_rect.y
```

---

However read the documentation. [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

So you should rename `player_rect` to `rect`. [Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) should normally use the CapWords convention. So rename `palette` in `Palette`:

```py
class Palette(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
        self.speed = speed
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,30,100)

    # [...]
```

```py
player = Palette(x, y, speed)
enemy = Palette(x*9, y, speed)
```